# Retrieving usear account name from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How to get current logged user account name from windows service? Account is not local - it is domain account.
Every method that I have tried was not good and returned only LocalService account.

Comment: A windows service runs without any users being logged in. What do you expect to happen if no users are logged it? If multiple people logged in?

Comment: What shows up on the "Log On" tab when you configure your service? And what specifically have you tried?

Comment: @Oded Yes, Windows services run without any user logged on but, a Windows service requires an account under which it will be running. I believe he's looking for the account under which the windows service is running.

Comment: @OnlyYou - The description (in particular "returned only LocalService account"), suggested to me that logged in user is just what the OP is looking for - not the service account. See [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003279/retrieving-usear-account-name-from-windows-service#comment15777121_9003322) from Novakov.

Answer (score 0):

I did use this method `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(False).Name` in the `System.Security.Principal` namespace and it worked. I'm running VS2010 and .NET Framework 4

I added a line in my service to write the following string to a text file:

```
String.Format("Currently logged on account: {0}", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(False).Name)
```

It returned the corresponding Windows account under which the Windows Service was running.

When running under account `Local Service` it returned `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`

When running under my domain account `dom\name.lastname` it returned `DOM\Name.Lastname`

You can specify the account under which the service will run in the 'Log On' tab of the Service properties dialog.

Answer (score -1):

You service is running in context of user LocalService. If you want to get name of user logged to interactive/RDP session (there could be none, one or more logged users) you have to use Terminal Services API using PInvoke. Here is the starting point for this: [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.WTSEnumerateSessions)

Comment: A service _may_ be running as `LocalService`, but does not have to.

Comment: @Oded: "returned only LocalService account." I think I can safely assume that service *is* running as LocalService